# DOM Found 2 elements with non-unique id #woocommerce_meta_nonce error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I create a product on product page, Chrome console I see a host of errors

> [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #woocommerce_meta_nonce

```
<input type=”hidden” id=”woocommerce_meta_nonce” name=”woocommerce_meta_nonce” value=”7ea1b5e163″>
<input type=”hidden” id=”woocommerce_meta_nonce” name=”woocommerce_meta_nonce” value=”7ea1b5e163″>
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, did you got it resolved? if yes, how?